# Como dar cobertura de testes em aplicações Rails já concluídas?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, tdd

TDD, geralmente é utilizado durante o desenvolvimento. Mas e quando você entra em uma empresa, pega o código todo zuado e vê a necessidade urgente de melhorias e claro, cobertura de testes? Como proceder? Como testar se todas as funcionalidades estão implementadas e funcionais?

Comment: Esta pergunta não tem resposta! 100% de cobertura é loucura mesmo quando planejado desde o início. Só o que você pode fazer é ir escrevendo os testes aos poucos, começando pelo que te dá mais problema.

Comment: @user15694 Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow! Poderia explicar melhor, de preferência fornecendo fatos e dados?

Comment: Também acho que não tem resposta, o que eu faria seria, criar os testes para as principais funcionalidades da aplicação, assim já poderia começar a desenvolver e refatorar sem ter grandes dores de cabeça.

Answer (score 3):

Vou tentar deixar algumas dicas aqui:

- É impossível atingir cobertura total de testes. Faça uma análise do que é mais crítico / te dá mais trabalho / exige refatoração, e comece por aí.
- Evite testar código proveniente unicamente de bibliotecas externas, ou do próprio *framework*. Teste o **seu** código. Validações do ActiveRecord, por exemplo, já foram testadas pelos próprios desenvolvedores. ([Clique aqui](https://github.com/rails/rails/tree/master/activerecord) e veja a pasta "test" ali).
- Uma coisa bacana do Ruby/Rails é que ele te permite adicionar/sobrescreveras métodos em classes pré-existentes, tanto do Ruby (como a classe String) como do Rails (como as classes do ActiveRecord). Isso pode ser feito alterando a própria classe, através de *mixins* (no caso do ActiveRecord, por exemplo) ou, em alguns casos, até por herança (como a classe FormBuilder do Rails). Independente do método, é recomendável escrever testes também nestes casos. (para rodar todos os testes, mesmo os que estão em pastas diferentes das geradas automaticamente, use `[spring] rake test:all`)
- Testar views (HTML e Javascript) é complicado, e deve ser evitado em casos simples. Isto é, a menos que haja código desacoplado das views. Alguns *framworks*, como o AngularJS, têm maneiras próprias de teste, embora pareça bem "desafiador" se comparado com a simplicidade e desexigência de configuração do Minitest.
- Isso não tem a ver só com testes. Em alguns casos é importante criar suas próprias classes, isto é, classes que não são controladores nem modelos, mas contém lógica utilizada por eles, para deixar o código mais "limpo" e facilitar e legibilidade e também os testes. É bom lembrar que assim como é importante saber Javascript e não só jQuery, também é **muito** importante conhecer muito bem o Ruby, e não apenas o Rails. Isso te ajuda a definir bem a arquitetura adequada ao seu sistema.
- Leia, leia, leia, leia e leia mais um pouco. Se você sabe inglês, [faça uma pesquisa no Google](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=tdd%20rails) e encontrará ótimos posts de blogs discutindo boas maneiras de testar sua aplicação em Rails. Quem procura acha.